# Android onActivityResult in PreferenceFragmentCompat is never called -I tried multiple solutions

Tags: java, android

In my app I have settings activity which is ActivitySettings and they use `R.xml.preferences` from FragmentSettings. This FragmentSettings is a class extending PreferenceFragmentCompat in which I want `onActivityResult()` to be called after call `startActivityForResult()` inside this fragment but this `onActivityResult()` is never called.

What I have tried already:

1. solution like you see below,
2. `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent2, AppConstants.GRANT_ACCESS_TO_AUTO_BACKUP_FILE);`
3. `someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent2);` - newer, not deprecated API

```
   
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        (...)

        Preference prefAutoExportFolder = findPreference("notes_auto_export_folder");
        prefAutoExportFolder.setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
            Log.i("TAG", "Trying to get access the desired folder from FragmentSettings");
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            startActivityForResult(intent2, AppConstants.GRANT_ACCESS_TO_AUTO_BACKUP_FILE);
            return true;
        });
    }

    (...)
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
            Log.e("eee", "eee0");
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
            if (requestCode == AppConstants.GRANT_ACCESS_TO_AUTO_BACKUP_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e("eee", "eee1");
                if (resultData != null) {
                    Log.e("eee", "eee2");
                    Uri uri = resultData.getData();
                    spEditor.putString("auto_backup_uri", uri.toString()).apply();
    
                    DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getActivity(), uri);
                    Log.e("eee", "eee3");
                    try {
                        documentFile.createDirectory(getString(R.string.app_name_no_space));
                        DocumentFile dfFinalDir = documentFile.findFile(getString(R.string.app_name_no_space));
                        Log.e("eee", "eee4");
    
                        if (dfFinalDir.exists()) {
                            Util.initConfirmDialogNoNegButton(getActivity(), "You modified the auto backup folder.");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Util.doWhenException(getActivity(), e, "The problem with /" + getString(R.string.app_name_no_space) + "/ folder");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.e("eee", "eee5");
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public class ActivitySettings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        (...)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentSettings()).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
        Log.e("eee", "eee0");

    }
```